# transfer value to another page PHP

Tags: php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) and $_POST['searcheditem'] != "") {
    $value = $_POST['searcheditem'];
    header("Location : anotherpage.php");
}
```

I use this code in my project, but when I am redirected to `anotherpage.php` I can't use `$value`. It is not equal to  `$_POST['searcheditem']` at that page.

What can I do?

Comment: Put it into `$_SESSION`?

Comment: Or put it in the url.

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 options in this case:

### 1. Use a query string

```
$value = $_POST['searcheditem'];
header("Location : anotherpage.php?myValue=".$value);

// then inside anotherpage.php   
echo $_GET['myValue']; // make sure to sanitize this data
```

### 2. Use Sessions

```
$value = $_POST['searcheditem'];
$_SESSION['myValue'] = $value; // make sure to use session_start() at the top of the page
header("Location : anotherpage.php");

// then on the anotherpage.php page
// make sure you call session_start() at the top of this page too
echo $_SESSION['myValue']; // make sure to sanitize this too
```

Comment: your comments give more clarity +1

Comment: Thanks :) We all have been there, so it's better to make it as clear as possible

Comment: Thanks a lot! You helped me so much!

Comment: @asprin Can you tell me please what did you meant under "sanitirize"? I used a query string and in anotherpage.php when I push any submit button an error is occured: Undefined index: course in bla bla bla. I think after submit button is pressed the $_GET['myValue'] loses its value and the error occures in line $value=$_POST['myValue'];

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways, either can set it in session or can pass like query string

Query string method:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) and $_POST['searcheditem'] != "") {
    $value = $_POST['searcheditem'];
    header("Location : anotherpage.php?value=$value ");
}
```

Session Method:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) and $_POST['searcheditem'] != "") {
        $value = $_POST['searcheditem'];
        session_register("value"); // USE THIS ONLY IF YOUR PHP VERSION IS < 5.3.0
        $_SESSION["value"] = $value;
        header("Location : anotherpage.php");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You can't even imagine how great help you did

Comment: I think session_register is removed since PHP 5.4 http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php

Comment: @KostasMitsarakis thanks for updating me, added comment on my answer.

Comment: @ShamilOmarov if it solves your issue, think of accepting it. This will help people to identify the solution http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work